# Editing the Elsa Dashboard & Designer

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface, designer, elsa-workflows

I'm currently working on a project which aims to deliver a "low-code" solution for integrating workflows. I'm very impressed by Elsa since it already comes with a lot of functionality that I was looking for.
Since the projcet goes into the direction of "low-code" the center of user Interaction will be the Dashboard/Designer.
I was wondering if it's possible to modify the components the designer uses? E.g. I'd like to integrate a Component that let's the user define the Workflow-Name and other input parameters when the "Create Workflow"-Button is clicked or remove existing activites or edit the toolbox in general.
I know that the components that are used by default are defined here

```
<body>
    <elsa-studio-root server-url="@serverUrl" monaco-lib-path="_content/Elsa.Designer.Components.Web/monaco-editor/min">
        <elsa-studio-dashboard/>
    </elsa-studio-root>
</body>
```

But I don't know where to find the monaco-lib-path neither if I'm able to edit what I'll find there. I'm very new to ASP.NET and web development in genereal, so I'll be very thankful if somebody can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there are not that many features to facilitate UI customization, there are some capabilities for customizing activities like their icons as described [here](https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/docs/next/extensibility/extensibility-designer-plugins#custom-activity-icons).

In [Elsa Roadmap](https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core#roadmap) V3.0
there's an item to make the dashboard modular & themeable. But until its implementation, you have the option to fork the designer which is developed using stenciljs, and make your desired changes, or even create your UI from scratch and just consume the Elsa API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would be the best way to fork the designer? By using the npm package? Or is there a better way?

Comment: You can fork it from it's github [repo](https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/tree/master/src%2Fdesigner)